# Error SQL71501 on exporting Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm getting a strange error when exporting an Azure SQL Database. Exports had been working fine until some recent schema changes, but it's now giving me Error SQL71501.

The database is V12, Compatibility Level 130 (although the `master` database is still Compatibility Level 120).

The problem seems to be caused by a new table-valued function, which uses the built in [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx) function. There were already stored procedures using `STRING_SPLIT` and they don't seem to have affected the export, but the function (which compiles OK, and is working fine) seems to cause a problem with the export.

The function below is a simplified version of the real one, but causes the same problem.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestFunction](
    @CommaSeparatedValues VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN

    SELECT      c.ClientId,
                c.FullName

    FROM        dbo.Client c

    INNER JOIN  STRING_SPLIT(@CommaSeparatedValues, ',') csv
    ON          c.ClientId = csv.value
```

The complete error message given in the Import/Export history blade is as follows:

> Error encountered during the service operation.
>
> One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
>
> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[TestFunction]: Function: [dbo].[TestFunction] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT].
>
> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[TestFunction]: Function: [dbo].[TestFunction] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[Client].[csv], [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT].[csv] or [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT].[value].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Xiaochen from Microsoft SQL team. We are already working on the fix of this issue. The fix will be deployed to the export service in next few weeks. In the same time, the fix is already available in the latest DacFX 16.4 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/09/20/sql-server-data-tools-16-4-release/). Before we fix this issue in the service, you can download the DacFX 16.4 and use sqlpackage to work around.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAzure validates Schema,references of the objects when you export database,if any of the references fails like the  below one in your case

> Error SQL71501: Error validating element [dbo].[TestFunction]: Function: [dbo].[TestFunction] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT].

the export won't succeed..So you will need to resolve those errors,prior to export..

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt684588.aspx),you will need to set the compatibility level to 130

> The STRING_SPLIT function is available only under compatibility level 130. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server will not be able to find and execute STRING_SPLIT function

**Update:**

I was able to repro the same issue and only current workaround is to delete the table valued function,that is referencing system function and export DACPAC,once export is done,recreate  the table valued function  :(

I have raised the issue here:please upvote..

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/16722646-azure-database-export-fails-when-split-string-is-i

Comment: That's the problem - there's nothing invalid in that function! It compiles and runs just fine. STRING_SPLIT is a built in system function, so I can't see why the export process is complaining about it.

Comment: The Compatibility Level is already 130, and the STRING_SPLIT function has been working fine in a bunch of stored procs for a while now.

Comment: I will try to repro ,once i have access today

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar. All I did to repro was add the function I mentioned in the question, then do an export.

Comment: @JonathanSayce:i was able to repro the same,see update for workaroubd

Answer (score 0):

Data Migration Assistant did it for me. First run an assessment on the schema, on success, run your migration https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595/